# getting resource as stream returns InputStream must not be null

Tags: java, image, path

I'm trying to get an image in this way:

```
Node rootIcon = new ImageView(new Image(this.getClass().getResourceAsStream("folder.png")));
```

I guess that I need to place the image in another folder or to set the path to it in other way. The image is in `src\main\resources\icon` and the class itself is in `src\main\java\package\package\package\class`

how to find out what path I need to set or where shall I put the image to?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `.getResourceAsStream("/icon/folder.png")`. If you use maven then, the content of src/main/resouces is automatically added to your jar file. Eclipse for example adds that folder to the calls path, if it is a source folder. So running from Eclipse should work too.